# How to move module under one vendor to another vendor with the same functionality in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, code-generation

I wanna move a module under `app/code/vendor1` directory to `app/code/vendor2` . I know that I should replace all namespace from `vendor1/module1` to `vendor2/module2` and replace all `vendor1_module1` to `vendre2_module2` (for example in registration.php file) and replace other things. so what is the best way to move a module in one directory into another module directory with the same functionality?

Comment: why do you want to move the modules/code ?

Comment: I get a sample module from github I wanna mode it to my vendor directory and then I will customise it

Comment: I wanna move it to my vendor directory and then I will customise it

Answer (score 0):

> There is no tool for migrating module functionality.
>   One more option is if you want to override the functionality, you can
>   override/extend the class instaed of migration.

You need to change the naming convention of the module you want to move by your module.

Check if the module has any dependency and migrate accordingly. if module dependents on other/core modules make sure you have to follow the dependency.